# How to avoid hard coding DB name in SQL synonym creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, synonym

Working with SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a script full of following statements:

```
create synonym [synonym_name] for [linkedServerName].[databaseName].[ext].[tableName1]
create synonym [synonym_name] for [linkedServerName].[databaseName].[ext].[tableName2]
```

**Question:** 
1. Is there any way to avoid 4 part naming. especially hard coded DB name

2. There is an existing script for LinkedServer creation. Can this be used while creating synonyms?
3. What would be the best way to create synonyms for multiple Table/Views?

   ```
   declare @Server sysname,
   @db sysname,
   @Schema sysname,
   @Table sysname,
   @statement varchar(max)

   SELECT @Server = 'Venice',
   @db = 'venice1', 
   @Schema = 'ext'

   EXEC('CREATE SYNONYM synonym_name1  FOR '+ @Server +'.'+ @db +'.' + @Schema  + '.Table1')
   EXEC('CREATE SYNONYM synonym_name2  FOR '+ @Server +'.'+ @db +'.' + @Schema  + '.Table2')
   ```

**Thoughts:** Is this the only way?

Comment: Yes, cause that's what the syntax of synonym.

Comment: As far as I know that is indeed the only way to do it

Comment: I assumed so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @Server sysname,
        @db sysname,
        @Schema sysname,
        @Table sysname,
        @statement varchar(max)

SELECT @Server = 'ServerName',
       @db = 'DatabaseName',
       @Schema = 'SchemaName',
       @Table = 'TableName'

set @statement = 'CREATE SYNONYM synonym_Name  FOR '+
                  @Server +'.'+ 
                  @db +'.' + 
                  @Schema  + '.' + 
                  @Table 

EXEC (@statement)
```

Comment: Assuming, same would apply for LinkedServer Name on the same statement?

Comment: See my edited answer. Of course, you can convert this to a stored procedure.

Comment: If there are 20+ synonym needs to be created, should there be 20+ statements in that case? Or what are the best ways to create multiple synonyms in same statement?

Comment: Without knowing the exact details it's very hard to answer. Does this script need to be applied once or repeatedly? should the synonym names be dynamic as well? What other operations you need to perform in this script? In my answer I've tried to give you a solution to the question in the title of your question. If it's not good enough, please explain your needs in greater details.

Comment: Your answer was perfect. I just happen to have more requirement (sorry for the confusion). This script will be run once. One script is dedicated for all synonym creation for the entire project. There is extra script to create the LinkedServer already. Should the synonym creation be merged in that script? In existing script 20+ sysnonym is required to be created for 20+ VIEW (from different DB)

Comment: First of all, I'm glad to read my answer was perfect, but the way to show it on SO is to vote up and accept, and not by comments. Second, If the script should run only once, I would probably write the entire `Create Synonym` statements hard coded. If you needed to manipulate synonyms dynamically, I would probably suggest creating a table for synonyms with the 5 columns and use triggers for insert, updates and deletes to create the and execute the `create synonym` statements dynamically.

Comment: Great help. Much appreciated. Was trying to execute your answer hence late in accepting it. Done now!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's the only way. Per [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) the `Synonym` creation syntax requires the DB name as can be seen below unless you are taking help of dynamic SQL.

```
-- SQL Server Syntax

CREATE SYNONYM [ schema_name_1. ] synonym_name FOR <object>

<object> :: =
{
    [ server_name.[ database_name ] . [ schema_name_2 ]. object_name 
}
```